# Camera still moving after locking

Tags: 3d-view, camera, settings

Good day
My camera is locked in Location/Rotation and Scale but I can still change Location/Rotation and Scale when I am scrolling on it. It seems it is not possible to lock its position.
The thing is, when I am out of camera view it is locked and it cant be moved. When I press "0" to go into camera view i can manipulate it. Was this always like this or is this a new thing?

Comment: it is locked for me, in or out of camera view, in the latest Blender version

Comment: Can you move, rotate or scale it in camera view with pressing G, R, S, or just by entering values or moving sliders in the _Transformation_ fields? The latter is intentional, I guess and it was the same in  older versions as well.

Comment: https://youtu.be/an2j2mlZlls

I put the issue on youtube. I don't really thing it is a problem but still think of it as a weird behaviour. If something is locked, shouldn't it be locked?
As you can see, I am able to R,S,G in camera view. I am (a habit) sliding. Entering a number also moves it. It is also like this in 3.2.1
thank you anyway